# Orange Data Mining Widget Creation in Canvas

Tags: python, orange

I have a Orange python widget that I created.  I would like to make it a standard widget in Orange canvas.  I have reviewed several tutorials to do this so I understand the code that must be created but after that how do you import that code into the widget library in Canvas?

No problems at this point looking for a complete tutorial on widget creation and import into Orange Canvas.

Reviewed several tutorials both text and video but they fall short of successful importing the code into Canvas.

When I followed the widget creation on Orange and ran the install command "pip install -e ." from the setup directory the command executed successfully but when I open Orange Canvas the Demo OWDataSampler was not present.  Not sure how the setup tool knows how to update the Orange application to recognize where the application is installed.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it to work properly. Need to open the Orange command prompt, navigate to the directory that has the *setup.py* file, and run the `pip install -e .` command. The widget is listed properly in canvas.